# Sharing files across applications

Tags: c++, svn, code-sharing

We have a common functionality we need to share among several applications. We already have a few internal libraries, into which we put common code with a well-defined interface. Sometimes, though, there are problems with some code (typically a single or a few .cpp files) as it doesn't fit into an existing library and it is too small to make a new one.

Our current version control system supports file sharing, so usually such files are just shared between the applications that use them. I tend to consider it a bad thing, but actually, it makes it quite clear, as you can see exactly in which applications they are used.

Now, we are moving to svn, which does not have "real" file sharing, there is this `svn:externals` stuff, but will it still be simple to track the places where the files are shared when using it?

We could create a "garbage" library (or folder) and put such files there temporarily, but it's always the same problem that it complicates dependency tracking (which project use this file?).

Otherwise, are there other good solutions? How does it work in your company?

Comment: I too have been frustrated by SVN's apparent lack of a simple and robust way of doing this.  I previously used StarTeam, which while I disliked the way Borland were taking the product having acquired it from StarBase, it did at least do inter-project file sharing and tracking very well.  So if I were to answer the question, I's say you need a different tool. The difference of course (and SVN's primary feature) is *cost*.

Comment: @Clifford, at the same time it looks like a very basic feature, and could have easily been implemented. So I guess not many people find it useful as they don't add it to svn. But what do they do then - never share any code?

Comment: I think it is rather that SVN has a different philosophy and heritage.  I advocated moving to SVN at my previous employer for reasons of cost; my current employer was using it already (and are now considering alternatives). I am glad I did not stay at my previous employer to see the consequences of that decision!  It's great if you have never used anything better (or anything at all).

Comment: @Clifford: then, would you probably have a suggestion for something other than SVN that has a proper support for file sharing? I've checked mercurial and git, it seems they don't support this neither (only some sub-repository stuff quite similar to svn:externals and not really solving my problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just create a folder in SVN called "Shared" and put your shared files into that?  You can include the shared files into your projects from there.

Update:

Seems like you are looking for a 3rd party tool that tracks dependencies.

[Subversion and dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248348/subversion-and-dependencies/4425674#4425674)

Comment: Because in this case I won't know in which projects they are used (that's what I call dependency tracking).

Comment: btw: in our company only stable code goes into "shared".  We try to avoid sharing things like that between projects, believe it or not, because creating the dependency between project A and library C and project B and library C, can sometimes also inadvertently create a dependency between project A and project B.  That is A can't continue until C has been updated, C can't be updated until B is also updated.  ie. they may have different release schedules.

Comment: oh yes I have already faced this too. But here (it's a small company) people are not always ready to wait for a stable version, and will often share new code. I don't think there is something I can do about this...

Comment: thanks for your update, it could be a solution indeed (I will accept your answer unless something else arrive). Unfortunately, I could not find such a tool for C++ projects, Maven is java-targeted and it looks rather complicated when people try to use it for something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can only find out where a file is used by looking at all repositories.

Comment: That would be quite inconvenient... when I make a modification I have to ensure it does not break something, so I definitely need a list of dependencies.